# Meterializecss- Wordpress Dropdown Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I show the WordPress menu items but do not show the dropdown . How do I show the dropdown menu ?

**functions.php**

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'TNCTR-OnePage' ),) );
```

**Header.php**

```
 <div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav class="navbar-tp">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="brand-logo logo"></a>

     <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
      'menu'       => 'primary',
      'menu_class' => 'right hide-on-med-and-down'

    ));
  ?>
 <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
      'menu'       => 'primary',
      'menu_class' => 'side-nav',
      'menu_id' => 'mobilemenu',
      'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="slide-out" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'  
    ));
  ?>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**HTML ver.**
http://pasted.co/b2fc8b68

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you assigned a theme location? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: ie. 'theme_location'  =>'primary'',

Comment: I can not hide sub- item
http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/WyozBdQ.png